# Single instance without singleton pattern

Tags: c#

Kindly suggest me the best pattern which will suits the below need.

```
Class Base
{
    List<string> a;
    List<string> b;   
    public Base()
    {
        //"Calling Base"
    }
}
Class Der : Base
{
    GetListA()
    {
        return a;
    }
    GetListB()
    {
        return b;
    }
}
Class Der1 : Base
{
    GetListA()
    {
        return a;
    }
    GetListB()
    {
        return b;
    }
}

Main()
{
    Der1 obj1 = new Der1();
    Der obj= new Der();
    obj.GetListA();
    obj.GetListB();
    obj1.GetListA();
    obj1.GetListB();
}
```

when I use `obj1` or `obj2`, currently the base class constructor is getting called  every time a new object is created.

`Base` class is generating say 10k records. I want that to be generated only once and keep it for others to reuse it.

Its purely web server application and my application wont accept any static variables/object or singleton class. Without that I need to perform this task.

Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: Explain why you can't have static variables? What does this being a web server have to do with that statement?

Comment: My existing app will throughout the error, if i use static methods, variables

Comment: And why *wouldn't* you expect the base class constructor to be called?  Both of your objects are based on it, so of course it's going to be called.  That's how object inheritance works.

Comment: the logic behind is,  "GenerateRecords" is a method which is there in all the derived class. this method will generate huge amount of date which is common to all. I've similar code in all of my derived class(Say 5 types of derived class). Now I want to move the method "GenerateRecords" outside  and I want to make it as common one for all the class and should be called once and reused by others. I dont kw how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class Base
{
    static List<string> a;
    static List<string> b;   
    public Base()
    {
        if(this.a == null)
        {
             a = database.GetListitemsForA();
        }

        if(this.b == null)
        {
             b = database.GetListitemsForB();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to using a static variable is to use the [Application property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could use a property like this to void creating multiple instances of your class

```
public SomeClass Instance
{
     get
     {
          if (Application["SomeClassInstance"] == null)
          {
               Application["SomeClassInstance"] = new SomeClass();
          }
          return (SomeClass)Application["SomeClassInstance"];
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing here is 

    Class Base
    {
    
        void Run();
    }
    Class Derv1 : Base
    {
        void Run();
    }
    Class Derv2 : base
    {
        void Run();
    }

Run() is creating huge amount of records. So I want to create a Run() method which will be executed only once irrespective of how my class it derived.

I cannot create singleton is the condition.